# Underscore - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm using Underscore templates with BackBone to display the content. Unfortunately I'm receiving the error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

The code is:

```
                    <script type="text/javascript" id="results-tpl">
                <% if(remainingPlaces>0 && remainingPlaces<10){
                      availability_class = 'limited-availability';
                      bookable = 'booking__bookable';
                  }
                  else if(remainingPlaces>9)
                  {
                      availability_class = 'available';
                      bookable = 'booking__bookable';
                  }
                  else{
                      availability_class = 'sold-out';
                      bookable = '';
                  }%>
                  <div class='booking__event__availability__box' data-eventID='<%-ID%>'>
                        <span class='time <%=availability_class%>  <%=bookable%>'><%=startTime%></span>
                        <span class='availability'><%=(remainingPlaces>0 && remainingPlaces<10) ? 'Only' : ''%> <%=remainingPlaces%> left</span>
                  </div>
                </script>
```

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Nick

Comment: Add the line `<%debugger%>` with your debugger (Google Dev, Firebug) open and then step through your code until you find where it errors out. If you're still having issues update your question

Comment: unrelated but might as well give feedback... having an if block in a template that modifies the model isn't really a good practice.  you should do these calculations and adjustments to the model within the view JS or in the model's parse() function.  the template should be purely focused on rendering

Answer (score 2):

`<script type="text/javascript" id="results-tpl">` replace type with: `text/template`

Comment: I don't that's the source of the error. All `<%-` does is escape html in the return value of the evaluated variable. A variable with a name like `ID` is most likely a `GUID` an `int`, each of which wouldn't cause the OP's problem

Comment: @nvaughan84 in my case i store all templates in separate html files